# How to use OnMarkerClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to make an application that allows to open new activity from a marker on the map with the method GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener but do not know how to use it. Does anyone help me?

Comment: do you want to open it when you click on the marker itself or on the infoWindow above?

Comment: sorry I'm trying to open it when click on balloon of information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use this:

```
getMap().setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

I used this code in my custom class that extends `MapFragment`
I've placed it in this method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

Comment: I'll make a blog post on the new Google Maps API v2 for Android somewhere tomorrow. check it at bon-app-etit.blogspot.com

Answer (score 2):

When touching Info window within a marker, if changing the current screen into another screen(class or Activity), Do this below;

```
private GoogleMap mMap:

.....
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....

private void setUpMap() {
.....
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        // When touch InfoWindow on the market, display another screen. 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Another.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, Another.class); ?