# How to perform map marker click in HERE MAP (android )

Tags: android, here-api

I am using a map.  I found an issue. **How do i know which marker is clicked?**

```
@Override
public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {..)
```

with On Gesture Listener i got this method  but how to find particular map marker object  and map marker title etc.

Comment: Refer links: [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958669/how-to-use-onmarkerclicklistener)

Comment: Hey thanks@Ankita Shah for comment but please read question carefully   i am using Here map  in android  refer links [here map api] (https://developer.here.com/)

Comment: Refer [this](https://github.com/DrJukka/NokiaX_Maps/blob/master/HereAPI_v2Porting/src/com/example/hereapi_example/MarkerDemoActivity.java) may be this will be help you.

Comment: Have you added markers on here maps?

Comment: yes , @Akash Patel  but in here map we use mapMarker insted of marker   
  
  mapMarkerDemo = new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(lat,lng), myImage);

        mapMarkerDemo.setTitle("markerTitle");
        mapMarkerDemo.setDescription(" this marker added for demo");
        hereMap.addMapObject(mapMarkerDemo);  

but i want to show toast or get map marker information on map marker clicked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To obtain which marker is clicked do like below in `onMapObjectsSelected` method.

```
for (ViewObject viewObject : list) {
    if (viewObject.getBaseType() == ViewObject.Type.USER_OBJECT) {
        MapObject mapObject = (MapObject) viewObject;

        if (mapObject.getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {

           MapMarker window_marker = ((MapMarker) mapObject);

           System.out.println("Title is................."+window_marker.getTitle());

              return false;
            }
        }
   }
```

You have to find out which object type is selected in loop as above.

Comment: well i was trying somthing like that   {   for (ViewObject obj : list) {
                if (obj.getBaseType().equals(MapObject.Type.MARKER)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                      
                        if(((MapMarker) list.get(i)).getTitle().contains("two")){
                            Toast.makeText(basicMapActivity,((MapMarker) list.get(i)).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           
                       
                }
            }

Comment: one more issue when i add markers with latLong arraylst  then  List<ViewObject> list   size() show always zero   why ..?

Comment: @kushal How you add markers on here map? edit question or ask another one.

Comment: ... wait a sec  adding one more questing with details

Comment: Check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585600/listviewobject-list-always-return-list-size-1-here-map-android

Answer (score 1):

```
  MapGesture.OnGestureListener onGestureListenernew= new 
  MapGesture.OnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPanStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanEnd() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMultiFingerManipulationStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMultiFingerManipulationEnd() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {

        for (ViewObject viewObject : list) {
            if (viewObject.getBaseType() == ViewObject.Type.USER_OBJECT) {
                MapObject mapObject = (MapObject) viewObject;

                if (mapObject.getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {

                    MapMarker window_marker = ((MapMarker)mapObject);
                     Log.d("danish","danish");
                    System.out.println("Title is................."+window_marker.getInfoBubbleHashCode());
                    Toast.makeText(m_activity,"Hello"+window_marker.getCoordinate(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTapEvent(PointF pointF) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPinchLocked() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPinchZoomEvent(float v, PointF pointF) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRotateLocked() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onRotateEvent(float v) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTiltEvent(float v) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongPressEvent(PointF pointF) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPressRelease() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTwoFingerTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

then add

```
m_mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(onGestureListenernew);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {

    for (ViewObject viewObject : list) {
        if (viewObject.getBaseType() == ViewObject.Type.USER_OBJECT) {
            MapObject mapObject = (MapObject) viewObject;

            if (mapObject.getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {

                MapMarker window_marker = ((MapMarker)mapObject);
                Log.d("Title->",window_marker.getTitle());
                Log.d("description->",window_marker.getDescription());
               return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```