# List<ViewObject> list always return list size() =1 Here map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Here I am adding marker on map:

```
hereMap.addMapObject(new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(lat,lng), myImage)
       .setTitle("marker"+geoCounter)
       .setDescription(" \nLatitude :" +lati+  "\nLongitude : "+ lng));
```

adding lat lng with array list of lat lng but when I add the marker with the help of:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {...}
```

`List<ViewObject>` list gives me the exact size of the added marker.

In this case, I get lat long with:

```
location.getLatitude()
location.getLongitude()
```

Here are the map markers on map:

[image: Image1]

Here I get size like this:

[image: Image2]

Comment: show `onLocationChanged` method code and array list of lat lng code also.

Answer (score 1):

Seems

```
public abstract boolean onMapObjectsSelected (java.util.List <ViewObject> objects)
```

A callback indicating that at least one ViewObject has been selected as a result of a user tapping on the map. So `objects` has only **selected** markers. For get access to all markers on map You should save the resulting Marker object in a collection (for example `ArrayList<MapMarker>`) of your choice  after you call `addMarker()`, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367644/6950238) answer. For example:

```
ArrayList<MapMarker> mMarkersList = new ArrayList();
...
MapMarker marker = new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(lat,lng), myImage)
            .setTitle("marker"+geoCounter)
            .setDescription(" \nLatitude :" +lati+  "\nLongitude : "+ lng)
mMarkersList.add(marker);
hereMap.addMapObject(marker);
```

then get it from `mMarkersList`:

```
MapMarker marker = mMarkersList.get(<number_of_marker>)
```

Comment: @ Andriy Omelechenko              .......................            in this case i am adding map marker help of arrayList of GeoCoordinate's   but when i add map marker through               
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {...}      its give me correct  size()  of map markers                                                                                                                              why this happen  in both case  map markers are added  on map    but   size ()  of  list are different  HOW ...?

Comment: "size () of list are different HOW" - I don't know why it happens, but if You controls marker by yourself (via list) You can solve your issues.