# How to perform map marker click in HERE MAP (Ios swift)

Tags: swift

I implement here map in my android project successfully, now I am working on iOS with swift so I have one issue about on map Marker.
In Android I have done this with this [MapMarkerClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523973/how-to-perform-map-marker-click-in-here-map-android)

But in iOS sdk I can't find this method in framework.

```
@Override
public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {..}
```

not with iOS Starter SDK or iOS Premium SDK

[image: android Here Map]

In this image I show a Map Marker with InfoBubble, now I want to do the same in ios. In ios I successfully add marker and circle  and InfoBubble as well but now problem is  if I add 5 marker and want to show InfoBubble with specific marker how I identify  which marker clicked.

In Android I implement Gesture  for map  and that gesture also work with ios but there is no method so find which map object clicked   like Android.

[image: android Gesture methods]

[image]

Comment: mean i found all gesture methods like (pan , pinch ) but this method is  missing  or i unable to find it ..:)

Comment: In not quiete sure I understand what you mean, Can you post an image of what you want to Achieve?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios  now its clear for you ..?

Comment: Here you have a tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Comment: Thanks @MagoNicolasPalacios  but this tutorials for  MapKit    i am working on Here Map   we can not use map kit in here map   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NMAMapViewDelegate and call its delegate function- 
    func mapViewDidSelectObjects(_ mapView: NMAMapView, objects: [NMAMapObject]) {
        print("select marker .....")

```
    mapMarker.showInfoBubble(self.winDowDisplay())
}
```